# How can i sign soap headers in WCF client

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, client, ws-security

I'm trying to call web service. The well-formed soap message (from service spec) looks like:

```
 <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:ebs="http://ebs.health.ontario.ca/" xmlns:edt="http://edt.health.ontario.ca/" xmlns:idp="http://idp.ebs.health.ontario.ca/" xmlns:msa="http://msa.ebs.health.ontario.ca/" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
      <wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" wsu:Id="X509-ED7F771775BF23B4CE137760623417313">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</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
      <ds:Signature Id="SIG-30" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:SignedInfo>
          <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
            <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="ebs edt idp msa soapenv" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
          </ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
          <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
          <ds:Reference URI="#TS-25">
            <ds:Transforms>
              <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="wsse ebs edt idp msa soapenv" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
              </ds:Transform>
            </ds:Transforms>
            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
            <ds:DigestValue>vVFQZIFYpfV/qk0X7lZpVuV9ao6Zckl4g78O+UXKCBE=</ds:DigestValue>
          </ds:Reference>
          <ds:Reference URI="#UsernameToken-26">
            <ds:Transforms>
              <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="ebs edt idp msa soapenv" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
              </ds:Transform>
            </ds:Transforms>
            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
            <ds:DigestValue>IqZOA4Ha1Ial3UqDc9Gl6wPLQF18xOSTBPR1/oj0mwY=</ds:DigestValue>
          </ds:Reference>
          <ds:Reference URI="#id-27">
            <ds:Transforms>
              <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="edt idp msa soapenv" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
              </ds:Transform>
            </ds:Transforms>
            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
            <ds:DigestValue>qHx6/vbUQhLVSqZmvJZSIEFXwSJ5TQhfgtJ3OfSnhdY=</ds:DigestValue>
          </ds:Reference>
          <ds:Reference URI="#id-28">
            <ds:Transforms>
              <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="ebs edt msa soapenv" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
              </ds:Transform>
            </ds:Transforms>
            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
            <ds:DigestValue>Mm83R8AW0mj1cGq4MwOxMiT9sI5nD8qo4KGcKfr/N8Q=</ds:DigestValue>
          </ds:Reference>
          <ds:Reference URI="#id-29">
            <ds:Transforms>
              <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="ebs edt idp msa" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
              </ds:Transform>
            </ds:Transforms>
            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
            <ds:DigestValue>f5Rcb1Z6o074KqaJDr7DDuIPIqaYS1OcYnZogVFWln0=</ds:DigestValue>
          </ds:Reference>
        </ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:SignatureValue>
          Uue2z5y0zbmbiG2qYXm83L5WYTeDL6uMasDMo6Ns7KLUmRndX0Iv+XGuA6EIG4HEpeCpCsjjFaQ8
          m1wZbEg+uLjug7QlkdhMCTA6gXEdlzgl7p9IGbnHgTGjPuY+af57ArwMAgktr5FXTKXLEPMQHyg/
          Isi6r1c12vFdERUai7w=
        </ds:SignatureValue>
        <ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-ED7F771775BF23B4CE137760623417314">
          <wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="STR-ED7F771775BF23B4CE137760623417315">
            <wsse:Reference URI="#X509-ED7F771775BF23B4CE137760623417313" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"/>
          </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
      </ds:Signature>
      <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-26">
        <wsse:Username>username</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">password</wsse:Password>
      </wsse:UsernameToken>
      <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-25">
        <wsu:Created>2013-08-27T12:23:54Z</wsu:Created>
        <wsu:Expires>2013-08-27T12:28:54Z</wsu:Expires>
      </wsu:Timestamp>
    </wsse:Security>
    <idp:IDP wsu:Id="id-28" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
      <ServiceUserMUID>282673</ServiceUserMUID>
    </idp:IDP>
    <ebs:EBS wsu:Id="id-27" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
      <SoftwareConformanceKey>1111</SoftwareConformanceKey>
      <AuditId>2222</AuditId>
    </ebs:EBS>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body wsu:Id="id-29" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <edt:list>
      <resourceType>CL</resourceType>
      <pageNo>1</pageNo>
    </edt:list>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

In wcf message log I see the following output

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Header>
<Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://edt.health.ontario.ca/EDTDelegate/listRequest</Action>
<h:EBS xmlns="http://ebs.health.ontario.ca/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:h="http://ebs.health.ontario.ca/">
<SoftwareConformanceKey xmlns="">1111</SoftwareConformanceKey>
<AuditId xmlns="">2222</AuditId>
</h:EBS>
<h:IDP xmlns="http://idp.ebs.health.ontario.ca/" xmlns:h="http://idp.ebs.health.ontario.ca/">
<ServiceUserMUID xmlns="">user11</ServiceUserMUID>
</h:IDP>
<h:MSA xmlns="http://msa.ebs.health.ontario.ca/" xmlns:h="http://msa.ebs.health.ontario.ca/">
<UserID xmlns="">user</UserID>
</h:MSA>
<ActivityId CorrelationId="a87eb831-b9d2-4333-8cae-f4138320fff1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/09/ServiceModel/Diagnostics">036f870c-b78f-40f7-ba27-7cdc8516f4fe</ActivityId>
<VsDebuggerCausalityData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/diagnostics/servicemodelsink"></VsDebuggerCausalityData>
</s:Header>
<s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<list xmlns="http://edt.health.ontario.ca/">
<resourceType xmlns="">CL</resourceType>
<pageNo xmlns="">1</pageNo>
</list>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

And I get exception which says

> SecurityVersion.WSSecurityJan2004 does not support header encryption.
>   Header with name 'EBS' and namespace 'http://ebs.health.ontario.ca/'
>   is configured for encryption. Consider using
>   SecurityVersion.WsSecurity11 and above or use transport security to
>   encrypt the full message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: [See here](http://webservices20.blogspot.co.il/2013/12/consuming-ebs-edt-soap-service-from-wcf.html) a detailed solution to consume this EBS-EDT service

Since you only need signature and not encryption try specifying that in the message contract itself:

```
[MessageHeader(ProtectionLevel=System.Net.Security.ProtectionLevel.Sign)]
```

Comment: Thanks, already find this out). Struggling with next issue.. Anyway thanks a lot